# Set active tab by clicking a link thats outside of the tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Im using the jQuery UI Tabs:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

How can I make a link on my page thats outside of the tabs, when clicked make a certain tab active? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

To get current active tab index:

```
var currentActive = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

To set current active tab:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", <number of tab> );
```

For example:

```
$('a').click(function(){
         $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
});
```

Comment: I assume the tabs are 0-indexed as well

Comment: Thank you for this! Wish I'd noticed this feature an hour ago!

Answer (score 2):

In IE10 option 'active' not work. I use instead of 'active'  option 'selected'.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", <number of tab> );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive marked @Secator's answer as correct as I can see from the documentation hes right. However for some reason it didnt work for me so instead I 'manually' simulated a click on the tab:

```
        $("#myTrigger").click(function(e) {
              $("#id-of-normal-tab-link").click();
              e.preventDefault(); //prevent default behavior of the a#myTrigger 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: tabNumber });
```

tabNumber starts with 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li ....> 
     <a href="#tab-number">Tab Title</a>
</li>
```

and them your url look like this: "[URL]#tab-number"

I hope help you.... Regards...