# Dynamically change active tab index jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to create a set of two buttons that will change the active tab in jQuery Ui. What I want to do is get the active tab index, and then go to the next tab, or the previous tab, based on which button is pressed.

So for example, if the active tab is number 3, clicking "moveLeft" would change it to 2. If "moveRight" is clicked, it would change it to 4. I know it's something like the following, but not quite:

```
var activeTab = $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

$('#moveLeft').click(function() {
    $(".tabs" ).tabs({ activeTab: -1 });
});
$('#moveRight').click(function() {
    $(".tabs" ).tabs({ activeTab: +1 });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set active tab by clicking a link thats outside of the tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641134/set-active-tab-by-clicking-a-link-thats-outside-of-the-tabs)

Comment: That one isn't dynamic. It doesn't get the current tab and add or subtract to it, it sets it based on a predetermined ID.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to add prev/next buttons. I needed that for a process with steps. I used jquery UI tabs and this worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ui-tabs').tabs();
        function GetSelTabIndex() {
            return $('#ui-tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        }
        function ShowTabs(stepN) {
            var n = parseInt(stepN);
            $('#ui-tabs').tabs('option', 'active', parseInt(GetSelTabIndex()) + n);
        }

        $('#moveLeft, #moveRight').click(function () {
            ShowTabs(this.value);
        })
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<button id="moveLeft" value="-1">Previous tab</button>
<button id="moveRight" value="1">Next tab</button>
```